# Chrome reinstallation does not allow me to update Chrome

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

I am running Ubuntu 22.04. My Google Chrome has not been updating for a while and has been asking for a reinstall.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling to update, but it doesn't work- the same Chrome cannot be updated, please reinstall message pops up.

[image: Popup message ss]

Output for `apt policy google-chrome-stable`:

[image: apt policy google-chrome-stable]

What could be causing it? How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: please add the output of `apt policy google-chrome-stable` to your question.

Comment: Yeah I've just updated the post with its output.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I was reinstalling a previous version of the chrome deb package that I hadn't deleted. So deleted that and installed the correct version. Thanks a lot.